# Reading cookie in cross-site context will be blocked in future Chrome versions

Tags: node.js, express

NGL, setting cors and cookies was the hardest part in my backend

```
 res
    .status(200)
    .cookie("token", token, {
      expires: new Date(
        Date.now() + Number(process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRE) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
      ),
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: true,
      sameSite: "none",
    })
```

these are the cookie options i've settled on
and while it works and doesn't return a cors error or get removed on reload in chrome like other options I used before this one, but still with these option chrome will block this cookie in a later update; what are the right options?
[This is the error i get in google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60NtJ.png).

Client is hosted on https vercel, backend is on https too using render.io, does this mean that I have to host the backend with the frontend?
**I don't want to host the client with the backend at all**

Answer (score 0):

Guys finally i've made it work.
in the backend instead of sending a cookie I only sent the token:

```
res.status(statusCode).json({ success: true, token });
```

and in the frontend I set the cookie as shown:

```
const res = await axios.post("user/login", values, {
        withCredentials: true,
      });

      if (res.status === 200) {
document.cookie = `token=${res.data.token}; SameSite=Strict; Secure; max-age=${30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000}`;
      }
```